# Handle webapp2 404 error in requesthandler class method instead of in a function

Tags: google-app-engine, webapp2

I'm using the webapp2 framework in Google App Engine (Python). In [webapp2 exception handling: exceptions in the WSGI app](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/exceptions.html#exceptions-in-the-wsgi-app) it's described how to handle 404 errors in a function:

```
import logging
import webapp2

def handle_404(request, response, exception):
    logging.exception(exception)
    response.write('Oops! I could swear this page was here!')
    response.set_status(404)

def handle_500(request, response, exception):
    logging.exception(exception)
    response.write('A server error occurred!')
    response.set_status(500)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    webapp2.Route('/', handler='handlers.HomeHandler', name='home')
])
app.error_handlers[404] = handle_404
app.error_handlers[500] = handle_500
```

How can I handle the 404 error in a `webapp2.RequestHandler` class, in the `.get()` method of that class?

**Edit:**

The reason I want to call a `RequestHandler` is to access the session (`request.session`). Otherwise I'm not able to pass the current user to the template of the 404 error page. i.e. on the [StackOverflow 404 error page](https://stackoverflow.com/abc) you can see your username. I would like to display the username of the current user on my website's 404 error page as well. Is this possible in a function or does it has to be a `RequestHandler`?

**Correct code based on @proppy's answer:**

```
class Webapp2HandlerAdapter(webapp2.BaseHandlerAdapter):
    def __call__(self, request, response, exception):
        request.route_args = {}
        request.route_args['exception'] = exception
        handler = self.handler(request, response)
        return handler.get()

class Handle404(MyBaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render(filename="404.html",
            page_title="404",
            exception=self.request.route_args['exception']
        )

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(urls, debug=True, config=config)
app.error_handlers[404] = Webapp2HandlerAdapter(Handle404)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The calling convention of error handler and request handler callables are different:

- `error_handlers` takes `(request, response, exception)`
- `RequestHandler` takes `(request, response)`

You may use something similar to [`Webapp2HandlerAdapter`](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2.html) to adapt a `webapp2.RequestHandler` to a callable.

```
class Webapp2HandlerAdapter(BaseHandlerAdapter):
    """An adapter to dispatch a ``webapp2.RequestHandler``.

    The handler is constructed then ``dispatch()`` is called.
    """

    def __call__(self, request, response):
        handler = self.handler(request, response)
        return handler.dispatch()
```

But you would have to sneak the extra exception argument in request `route_args`.

Comment: Could you give an example of a `RequestHandler` class that is derived from `Webapp2HandlerAdapter` and that handles the 404 error?

Comment: Also, every `RequestHandler` in my application is derived from a `BaseRequestHandler`. Should the error handler class be derived from both classes (`BaseRequestHandler` and `Webapp2HandlerAdapter`) then?

Comment: You can use `callable = Webapp2HandlerAdapter(handlers.HomeHandler)` to convert a handler in a callable.

Comment: But you would need to adapt `Webapp2HandlerAdapter.__call__` to somehow handle the extra `exception` argument.

Comment: The following exception is thrown: `TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)`. You can see my code, based on your answer, in the question. Any idea why the exception is thrown?

Comment: Yes, thats because of the extra `exception` argument :) As I said in my answer, you would have to adapt Webapp2HandlerAdapter in order to store it somewhere (for example `route_args`) so that it get dispatched to the method of your handlers.

Comment: Sorry about that. Now I get `method_name = request.route.handler_method 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'handler_method'`